# Spyder becomes non-responsive in Anaconda (py 2.7) running on Win 7 64-bit

Tags: python

I am very new to python and am using it for analyzing simulation data. The code I wrote in Anaconda (python 2.7) worked for a couple of times and now seems to become non-responsive.

I have tried re-starting the console, even uninstalled and installed again. But it does not work.
Can someone please point out the problem?

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!  Would you please post the text of the code that is not working for you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The text is over 100 lines. Is there a good way to post it here?

Comment: 100 lines is no problem.  Once you paste the code in the answer box, make sure to highlight it, and click the curly braces `{}` in the formatting toolbar.  That will make it show up in the standard coding format.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf as bpdf
import pandas as pd
pdf = bpdf.PdfPages("Dictra_graphs.pdf")
% matplotlib inline
os.getcwd()
path= 'C:\\Users\\prajo25.AD\\Desktop\\D7X sim'
os.chdir(path)
a=os.listdir(os.curdir)
it=7  #number of iterations completed
Time=[1, 5, 10, 30, 50, 80, 100, 150, 300, 500, 800, 1000]

newlist_wp=[]
newlist_bph=[]
file_Al=[]
file_bph=[]
i=0

while i<5:
    newpath=path+'\\'+a[i]
    os.chdir(newpath)
    for filename in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext == '.exp':
            os.rename(filename, base_file + '.txt')
    List_wt=['wt1.txt','wt2.txt','wt3.txt','wt4.txt','wt5.txt','wt6.txt','wt7.txt']
    List_bph=['npm1.txt','npm2.txt','npm3.txt','npm4.txt','npm5.txt','npm6.txt','npm7.txt']
    I=range(it+1)
    length=len(I)-1
    j=0
    while j < length:
        file_Al.append(np.array(pd.read_table(List_wt[j],sep='\s',names=["Distance in microns","NAN","wt-% Al"], index_col=False, skiprows=17, skip_footer = 671,engine='python'))*1000000)
        file_bph.append(np.array(pd.read_table(List_bph[j],sep='\s',names=["Distance in microns","NAN","wt-% Al"], index_col=False, skiprows=152, skip_footer = 68,engine='python'))*1000000)
        j=j+1
    newlist_wp.append(file_Al)
    newlist_bph.append(file_bph)
    file_Al=[]
    file_bph=[]
    i=i+1

i=0
k=0
r=7
while i<7:
    list_f=[newlist_wp[0][i], newlist_wp[1][i],newlist_wp[2][i],newlist_wp[3][i],newlist_wp[4][i]]
    list_bph=[newlist_bph[0][i], newlist_bph[1][i], newlist_bph[2][i], newlist_bph[3][i], newlist_bph[4][i]]
    a0=np.array(list_f[0])
    a1=np.array(list_f[1])
    a2=np.array(list_f[2])
    a3=np.array(list_f[3])
    a4=np.array(list_f[4])
    b0=np.array(list_bph[0])
    b1=np.array(list_bph[1])
    b2=np.array(list_bph[2])
    b3=np.array(list_bph[3])
    b4=np.array(list_bph[4])


    plt.figure(k+1)
    plt.grid()
    plt.plot(a0[:,0],a0[:,2]/1000000,'r--', label='D71')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(a1[:,0],a1[:,2]/1000000,'b--', label='D72')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(a2[:,0],a2[:,2]/1000000,'m--', label = 'D73')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(a3[:,0],a3[:,2]/1000000,'g--', label = 'D74')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(a4[:,0],a4[:,2]/1000000,'k--', label = 'D75')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.legend(loc=2, ncol=1)

    plt.ylabel('Wt.% of Al')
    plt.xlabel('Distance in microns')

    plt.figure(r+1)
    plt.plot(b0[:,0],b0[:,2]/1000000,'r--',label='D71')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(b1[:,0],b1[:,2]/1000000,'b--', label='D72')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(b2[:,0],b2[:,2]/1000000,'m--', label='D73')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(b3[:,0],b3[:,2]/1000000,'g--',label='D74')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')
    plt.plot(b4[:,0],b4[:,2]/1000000,'k--', label='D75')
    plt.title(str(Time[i])+'hours')

    plt.legend(loc=2, ncol=1)
    plt.ylim(ymax=1.2, ymin=0)
    plt.ylabel('Amount of gamma phase')
    plt.xlabel('Distance in microns')


    k=k+1
    r=r+1
    plt.show()

    i=i+1

q=0
for q in range(1,k+r-6): ## will open an empty extra figure :(
    pdf.savefig( plt.figure(int(q)) )

pdf.close()
```